# Video.js Playing a file which is on remote server

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I'm using the video.js and when the file is on the same server on which the http page resides the video is played ok.
When i move the file on an another http server and put a link to it in my web page the video is not played. Here is the error message

VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. [object Object]
 http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js:22

The file on remote server is accessible.
The code for web page is looking like this:

```
<HEAD>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.8/video.min.js"></script>

<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 -->
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</HEAD>

<p> This is HTML5 video demo</p>

<video id="my-video" class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640"   height="480"
poster="http://my_server//cover.jpg" data- setup='{"example_option":true}'>
<source src="remote_server_ip/test.flv" type='video/x-flv'>
<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a  web browser that
  <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports  HTML5 video</a>
</p>
</video>
```

Can video.js play files which are on another server?

Comment: Just to make sure: `src="remote_server_ip/test.flv"` is actually `src="http://remote_server_ip/test.flv"`, and the file plays when you paste the src into the address bar, correct?

Comment: Hm, http:// was missing and now it's ok for file which is on my server.

Comment: But for the file which is on another server (tube) the same linking is not working. Maybe due protection?

Comment: It seems i have figured out what is the problem but don't know how to solve it. The video on remote server is not available directly via GET request. Instead it is located under location specified in the Location field in response on the GET request. It seems video.js can't play files located in another URL.

Comment: I was wrong about Location field. The problem is that video.js adds a Referer header to the GET request, Is there any way to remove it?